# Xero OAuth 2 token

Tags: windows, oauth-2.0, console-application, xero-api

I'm new to Xero api and Is it possible to request Xero OAuth 2 token from the windows console app without giving redirect Url?
I tried several options and if not log and there is not created token, it has to show the popup for login.
I need to find a solution to do these actions only using the command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Xero APIs require apps to operate on behalf of a user. Connecting your app to a Xero account requires a user to grant consent in a web browser. This can be challenging if you’re building a back-end integration that doesn’t have a user interface.

For integrations like these, our CLI tool XOAuth allows you to establish an offline connection with a Xero user’s account directly from the command line. No web development required.

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api-guides/machine-2-machine